# How to implement JobScheduler to scan for Bluetooth beacons in the background?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

I am writing an app that scans for Bluetooth beacons when the app is in the foreground and the background. I have the foreground part figured out, but I do not know what to do for the background part, especially in android 8.0 and above where the system does not let the app run for longer that 15 minutes in the background.

The app needs to scan for beacons and get their mac address and UUIDs. Also, it should get the scan response because there is some information there that I need to decode and save. I have used the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le) to implement the foreground scanning using BluetoothLeScanner. As for background, I tried changing the scan mode to LOW_POWER, but the OS kills the app after around 15 minutes. Please note that I do not want a foreground service with a constant notification and I am fine with the scanning only running at intervals of ~15 minutes.

Many suggested the Android Beacon Library, but I could not find the required beaconLayout for the type of beacons that we use, Kontakt Beacon Pro BP16-3, and so Beacon Library does not detect them.

The information I need from the beacons include the unique ID and battery percentage. See [here] (https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/206294004-How-to-check-the-battery-level-on-your-beacons) for the details of where they are in the scan response.

I would appreciate any help with writing code to search for beacons in the background that would work on any Android version from 6.0 and up, or help with using Beacon Library with the beacon that I mentioned above.

**EDIT: Unique ID & Bluetooth from scan response**

When I use BLEScanner to scan for beacons, I can use ScanResult::getScanRecord() to get the scanRecord object. Then, I use the getServiceData() method to get a byte array whose first 4 bytes represent the unique ID in ASCII, the next two bytes are the firmware version in ASCII, and finally the last byte is the battery percentage in hexadecimal. I even confirmed the battery level with the official Kontakt app and so I am sure that it is correct.

When I use the Beacon Library, I could not find an easy way of getting a parsed version of the scan response. Instead, I have to use a NonBeaconLeScanCallback to get the byte array. Then, the byte array turns out to be

```
[2, 1, 6, 26, -1, 76, 0, 2, 21, -9, -126, 109, -90, 79, -94, 78, -104, -128, 36, -68, 91, 113, -32, -119, 62, -91, 68, 124, 56, -77, 8, 9, 75, 111, 110, 116, 97, 107, 116, 2, 10, -12, 10, 22, 13, -48, 68, 106, 69, 77, 52, 50, 68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].
```

It seems that the bytes from index 46-49 indicate the unique id in ASCII, in this case "DjEM". Moreover, the byte at index 52 is the battery percentage, in decimal; In this case, it is 68.

It seems that by using BLE scanner I can save a lot of headache in terms of parsing the unique ID and battery. However, it would be much harder to reliably implement background scanning. Hence, is there a way to combine the best of two, and get the bacon library to parse the unique ID and battery percentage?

**EDIT2: Beacon library message when not recognizing my beacon**

The beacon library is still failing to detect my beacon even though I use both the iBeacon and EddyStone beacon layouts. It prints the below in the logcat:

```
 processing pdu type 16: 0201060d166afe0206010a64f456425a4d08094b6f6e74616b74000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 16
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 0201060d166afe0206010a64f456425a4d08094b6f6e74616b74000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Ignoring pdu type 01
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some flexibility in your timings? If yes, then you can try WorkManager and something like a PeriodicWorkRequest. They're guaranteed to run even if app isn't active and if you set the interval at 15min, then it'll trigger at around 15+ min.

Comment: @Ryujin will the ble scannier be able to scan for every beacon or only beacons with that match a filter. In other words, if I give a full or empty scan filter, will it scan for every ble device when it runs in the background? Thanks.

Comment: Passing null to the scanfilter I think does that.  But this is already a different item from your main question.

Comment: @Ryujin It is related because If PeriodicWorkRequest allows me to scan for any beacon in the background, then that answers my question. Also, can I use PeriodicWorkRequest on any Android OS version?

Comment: The WorkManager is a general purpose background job API, it's not just for BLE.  It's back ported all the way back to API level 14.  See - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: @Ryujin Thanks, I'll take a look. I also came across BroadcastRecievers and pending intents. The BLE scanner has an option of providing a pending intent call back. Do you know which of Broadcasts or workmanager is more suitable for scanning for beacons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Kontakt.io docs linked, the battery level is also available in the scan response.  (Note:  the scan response is not *always* available when you detect a beacon packet, but it is often available -- it is provided by the Android OS and gets merged with the scan data when the scan response gets received.)  In a raw Android scan result bye array, the scan response is simply tacked on at the end of the regular scan data.

When using the Android Beacon Library, the scan response is also available, the Android operating system takes the scan response and stores it in the BluetoothDevice#name field.  (See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getName())).  The Android Beacon library, when it parses a beacon, copies that field into the Beacon#name field. So that information will be available to you as a string if you can parse a beacon and the device detects a scan response.

Two obstacles here:

1. Your Kontakt.io beacon does not appear to be advertising anything that is actually a beacon advertisement.  You might need to configure it to advertise the iBeacon format or perhaps the Eddystone-UID format.  Once you do that and you configure the Android Beacon Library with that layout, it will detect it.  Note that the bytes shown: `processing pdu type 16: 0201060d166afe0206010a64f456425a4d08094b6f6e74616b74000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 16
   This is not a matching Beacon advertisement.` do not correspond to iBeacon or Eddystone.  This appears to be some kind of proprietary 16-bit GATT Service advertisement (AD type 0x16). It has a 16-bit service UUID of 0x0102 which corresponds to nothing in the Bluetooth SIG list of [standard](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services) or [custom](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/16-bit-uuids-for-members) 16-bit UUIDs.  Your guess is as good as mine what it is!
2. The BluetoothDevice#name or the Beacon#name will be a String.  You will need to convert this to bytes, and then parse out the battery level as Kontakt.io describes in its scan response document.

Comment: It seems that due to the zeroes in the byte array, the getName() method only returns the first part before a zero appears. Is there no way to get the scanrecord using the beacon library? I would prefer to use the beacon library's background mode rather than implementing my own.

Comment: Right now the Android Beacon Library does not directly parse scan responses (it relies on the OS per above). This feature could certainly be added, and I don't think it would be terribly hard.  If you are interested in working on it as a pull request to the open source library, I can give you help to get started.  Alternately, you might be able to kludge something up to parse it out of a custom beacon layout with no code changes if you can make your Kontakt.io beacon advertise an iBeacon, AltBeacon or Eddystone standard beacon the library can decode and  the scan response is tacked on the end.

Comment: If you'd like to proceed with one of the above options, I'd suggest opening an issue here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues, which might make a easier place to discuss.

Comment: I will use a pull request, thank you. One more thing, if I do not setBackgroundMode to true and then go home, and wait around 15 mins for the OS to stop my app, will the beacon library automatically use JobScheduler to perform scans in the background. Also, if swipe away the app, will the beacon library attempt to restore it and perform scans? Does BackgroundMode need to be set to true or false for it to do that.

Comment: Also, how could I incorporate a JobScheduler into the beaconlibrary so that whenever any beacons are detected, it sends something to my server. Could I simply put my code to send to the server in the RangeNotifier?

Comment: And yes, jobs will be scheduled regardless of background mode.  If you kill your app the next job will still run on schedule within ~15 min.

Comment: So that means that the only difference between background and foreground mode is the difference in scanning time intervals right? And the only way to stop the jobs from running is to unbind the beaconmanager. Lastly, does my activity need to implement BootstrapNotifier or is it enough if it implements BeaconConsuner for the job scheduler and background processing to work.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between monitoring with a region where all of the identifiers are null and ranging? Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot.

Comment: Yes, you can use jobs without BootstrapNotifier.  Monitoring tells you just enter/exit events.  Ranging gives you callbacks every second with a list of detected beacons.  Both work with a Region definition telling you what beacons will match.  All nulls matches all beacons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191362/discussion-between-sepehr78-and-davidgyoung).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read the battery level of your Kontakt.io beacon simply by scanning for advertisements.  You must connect to it using an onboard GATT service (more on that below.)

For general scanning in the background and foreground you can certainly use the Android Beacon Library.  You probably want to use the iBeacon layout:

```
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

But while the above will detect your beacons it won't tell you the battery level.  That is because Kontakt does not advertise its battery level.  To get it, you must separately connect to the GATT service with Service UUID = 0x1805 and then read the value of the characteristic with Characteristic UUID = 0x2a19.  This will return a value between 0-100 indicating the percentage level of the battery.

You can see details of how this is accessed in Kontakt.io's "Other BLE Scanners" Section [here](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/206294004-How-to-check-the-battery-level-on-your-beacons).

OK, so this doesn't tell you how to write code to read that value.  To do so, you need to learn the basics of Bluetooth LE GATT programming, which takes a bit of learning.  A good place to start is [here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-leblueto)    You'll need to program a few steps:

1. Scan for the device (the Android Beacon Library does this part for you using its Ranging APIs, giving you the device MAC address in the `String macAddress = beacon.getBluetoothAddress();`)
2. Connect to the device.  If you have used the library to do the discovery, you can get a reference to the device and connect to it with `bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress).connectGatt(...)`
3. Discover the services
4. Look for the 0x1805 service uuid in the list of services from the above step.
5. Discover the characteristics for the discovered service from above
6. Look for the 0x2a19 characteristic uuid in the list of characteristics from the above step.
7. Read the value of the above discovered characteristic.

All of the above might be put into a scheduled job to run every 15 minutes, using a stored copy of the nearby beacons' bluetooth MAC address strings.

That's not easy super I know.  I wish I could give you a few lines of code to just get that battery level, but unfortunately it doesn't work that way. Welcome to the world of Bluetooth LE GATT programming!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! In the link I attached it says that the battery level and unique id are included in the response packet. In fact, when I turn on debug mode in the beacon library and look at the logcat, I can see the byte response of the beacon and how the library did not know how to parse it. When I convert that byte response to ASCII, I can see the unique id in there. Does this mean that I still need to use GATT?

Comment: Also, if I use a job scheduler, does the background scanning scan for every beacon or only beacons in the region? And is it easy to implement the background scanning myself or is it too much of a hassle and should I just use the beacon library.

Comment: Can you paste the scan results (with scan response) to the bottom of your question along with a description of what you think is the battery level?

Comment: Implementing background scanning yourself is easy for one device model, but not easy to get reliably working on all devices!  I do a huge amount of work on the library to make it as reliable as possible and I still get tripped up by some devices.  If you end up having to do GATT I would let the library do the scanning, save the Bluetooth MACs  to shared preferences, then use your Job to just process the last devices seen -- read the MACs from shared preferences, connect to each via GATT and read the battery level, then clear shared preferences of MACs.

Comment: I edited my post. Also, the beacon library is still not detecting my beacon. I added the message it prints in my post.